# using apply function based on a previous row/ Converting a looping statement to an apply function

Tags: python, vectorization, apply

I am currently working on a file which has multiple users profile changes based on every single time their profile was updated for a particular instance. I would like to make the column a 1 if there was a change from the previous profile in that particular column and keep it a zero if there wasn't a change. 
The file looks like this:

id date gender status     name meal    smoker

01 ---- male   married    ---  veg       yes

01 ---- male   unmarried  ---  non-veg   yes

01 ---- male   unmarried  ---  non-veg    no
...

I have a running code using loops which checks for a particular user in a data frame and then if the previous row for a particular column is not the same as the current one, then it would give the output as 1, indicating a change and 0 if there was no change.

the code is as follows:

```
     h = len(sample2.columns)
     i=1
     while(i<len(sample2)):
        if(sample1.iloc[i,1] == sample1.iloc[i-1,1]):
            k=5
            while(k<h):
                if(sample1.iloc[i,k]!=sample1.iloc[i-1,k]):
                    sample2.iloc[i,k] = 1                   
                k=k+1
        i=i+1
```

where sample2 has been reindexed with all the elements of sample1.

Is there a way of optimizing this code either using apply or iterrows or any vectorization as this data has over 5 million rows and looping through each element takes a lot of time.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around what you want. My best guess from the code: for those rows where the `date` matches the previous `date`, for the columns `meal` and `smoker`, if they show a value that differs from the one in the previous row, you want to fill a `1` in the matching location in a structurally similar dataframe.

But your description seems to suggest it is the `id` column you want to match to begin with. A sample input and output would really help to solve this problem.

Comment: @Jordi I want to be able to match the id and for all the instances of the ID I want to check each instance against the previous entry to see if there has been a change in any of their preferences

Comment: in this case, as there is a change from married from unmarried it should be reflected in the 2nd row corresponding to the unmarried instance as 1 whereas a shift from male to male would result in a 0

Comment: And what about the first row of that id? Should there be a zero (reflecting no change), missing value (reflecting no possible comparison), or even a 1 (reflecting new information)?

Comment: it should be a 0 reflecting no change, the only time there is a one is supposed to be when there is an explicit change

Comment: @jordi, thank you so much, I am a new member to the stackoverflow community and greatly appreciate your help. I'll run the code soon and see how that fits in.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create minimal example for illustration
ids = [1,1,2,3,3]
pref1 = ['v','n','v','n','n']
pref2 = ['s','n','n','n','s']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'pref1':pref1, 'pref2':pref2})

# Create simple function to identify changes
def identify_changes(a):
    return (a == a.shift()).astype(int)

# Apply function on pref columns, grouped by id
new = df.iloc[:,1:].groupby(df['id']).apply(identify_changes)

# Change names of res and bind it to original df
new.columns = 'new_' + new.columns
pd.concat([df, new], axis = 1)
```

The function `identify_changes`

- Compares its input `a` with its `shift`ed (or lagged) self (by exploiting the fact that within `pandas`/`numpys`, array operations are vectorized).
- Turns the resulting `bool` into `int`, turning `True` into 1 and `False` into 0 automatically.

The `apply` function is perfectly suited to apply this (or any) function to the columns (or rows) of a `DataFrame`. So this solution is easily extended to multiple columns.

Comment: In my actual dataset, I have about 250 columns, is there any easy way to generalize it so I can use the function by index?

Comment: Also, when I run the following code, everytime it encounters a new id, it stores that value as 1, is there a way to avoid doing that

Comment: I extended the example with a second preference column. Indexing can be done with `iloc`. You can leave out `id` in the column selection, as it is explicitly included now (`df['id']`). It is a good idea to make sure the original dataframe is actually sorted by 'id'. If so, you can horizontally add the resulting columns to the original dataframe.

Comment: I added the steps to bind the new columns with the original df (when properly sorted by `id` before doing the calculations).

Comment: Yup, this is working as I wanted it to, Thank you so much. 
Just a follow up question, if I wanted to record the number of times there were changes made based on the day value, is there a way of keeping extra variables in the function to keep track of daily, weekly and monthly number of changes per user?

Comment: I think it can be done, keeping the function `identify_changes` as it is, using `resample` to sum over the newly added columns. 1) order by id, 2) calculate and add new columns, 3) set date column as index 4) use `resample` and `sum` to calculate sums per time range. If you're stuck, consider a new question. You might find that people find it easier to help when they get a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) their best answer. I had fun! @ShikharSharma